# How can I make the radiator heat my room more efficiently?

Tags: heating, radiator

In my room at Uni my radiator gets really, really hot, yet the room stays pretty cold.

Is there anything I can do to make it more efficient without losing my deposit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a portable fan to blow air across the radiator so that the room becomes more evenly heated. The moving air will actually extract more heat from the radiator than still air would, so you may find that this makes the room noticeably warmer.

Comment: I will give that a spin and see if it helps

Comment: Well its made real difference :)